# when the dom is loaded exactly what's going on?

Tags: dom

When we say, DOM is loaded , I mean the DOM but not the page.
 What happens in the browser! When  DOM is loaded? Please can you be more precise.
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"When the DOM is loaded but not the page" doesn't really mean much.  As the HTML is loaded, the browser renders it as the static page you see on your screen.  The DOM is the representation that allows interaction with those elements.

For example, I can create objects in JavaScript and then manipulate them, but I've only manipulated a simple object.  A DOM object, looks like the same object, but it's tied to a correlating [X|XH|H]TML object; so that when I call a method on this object, it didn't just interact with a container of information but its constituent node on the page.  Consequently, you can't use a DOM method on an element that hasn't been rendered yet.

Tangible example:

```
/* Manipulating a standard JavaScript object */
var obj = { firstProp: "InitialValue",
            secondProp: "somethingelse",
            aMethod: function(){ this.firstProp = "Changed" }
           }
    console.log(obj.firstProp); // Ouput is "InitialValue"
obj.aMethod();
    console.log(obj.firstProp); // Output is "Changed", but nothing is effected other than that value

/* Here is a method called on a DOM element; pretend it's an input/text */
var obj2 = document.getElementById("testId");
    obj2.value = "This is your new text box value";
```

In the second example, you see that I didn't just change an arbitrary object's value.  I've change the HTML's rendered representation of that object.

That's the best way I can think to explain it at the moment.

Comment: yes thank you, I understand a little the principle how does it work

Comment: I'll keep using HTML examples because they're easy to grasp.  As the browser parses the page, it keeps a reference of where the elements are and already knows what methods are available to it; including it's parent/child objects.  So in the above example, `document.getElementById` is a selector method and stores a reference in obj2 (where document is the top node, "testId" is a child node, and "get..." is the way of selecting).  Then `value` is an available method to change the value of the corresponding text box.  If that doesn't clarify, then I don't think I exactly understand your question.